# How to create a popup message with tkinter if certain conditions are met?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, user-input

As a way to learn python, I'm creating a program that tracks my daily progress while I'm learning to play the bass guitar. One of the things I'm tracking (among others) is up to 3 artists that I practiced each day. The code below is only a tiny portion of the rest of the code I'm working on, but it should be enough to explain my problem.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import ttk, Menu

# Create empty Lists
raw_artists_list, raw_genre_list = [], []
collapsed_artists_list, collapsed_genre_list = [], []

# Define click function
def click_done():
    input_a1 = str(entrybox_a1.get())
    input_a2 = str(entrybox_a2.get())
    input_a3 = str(entrybox_a3.get())

    # Append to raw artist list
    raw_artists_list.append(input_a1)
    raw_artists_list.append(input_a2)
    raw_artists_list.append(input_a3)

    # Determines if new artist has been added and asks for it's genre
    for art in raw_artists_list:

        if art not in collapsed_artists_list:
            
            collapsed_artists_list.append(art)
            input_gen = input("What is "+art+"'s genre?")
            collapsed_genre_list.append(input_gen)

        else: continue

# GUI 
window = Tk()
window.title("Program Title")
window.geometry('300x100')

# Artist 1
lbl_a1 = Label(window, text="Artist 1: ", width=20)
lbl_a1.grid(sticky="w", column=0, row=10, padx=10)
entrybox_a1 = Entry(window, width=15)
entrybox_a1.grid(sticky="w", column=1, row=10)

# Artist 2
lbl_a2 = Label(window, text="Artist 2: ", width=20)
lbl_a2.grid(sticky="w", column=0, row=11, padx=10)
entrybox_a2 = Entry(window, width=15)
entrybox_a2.grid(sticky="w", column=1, row=11)

# Artist 3
lbl_a3 = Label(window, text="Artist 3: ", width=20)
lbl_a3.grid(sticky="w", column=0, row=12, padx=10)
entrybox_a3 = Entry(window, width=15)
entrybox_a3.grid(sticky="w", column=1, row=12)

# Done button
btn_done = Button(window, text='Done', command=click_done)
btn_done.grid(column=1, row=15)

window.mainloop()
```

[image]

Once I've inputted my artists for the day, lets say artists A, B and C, I want my program to recognize that these artists are new entries, and then myself input each new artist's genre (which I've already managed to figure out but through the terminal). The best way to do this I figure is to display a popup message for every new artist asking for that artist's genre. Lastly, once the program recognizes that all new artists' genres are accounted for, then clear the contents of the previous entries.

Bonus points: Again, this is only a tiny chunk from what I'm working on, and I'm starting to become confused of where or how all sections of my code must be ordered and nested. For example, as a daily progress tracker, certain things must happen before the next day's entries are recorded. In other words, things are getting messy. If you have any suggestions or recommendations for tutorials of how to ideally structure code for a GUI progress tracking program, that would be very much appreciated.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `simpledialog.askstring()` to replace `input()`.  Also you can use dictionary to holds the artist's name and genre instead of two separate lists.

Below is a modified `click_done()`:

```
from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring
...

artist_list = {}

def click_done():
    for entry in (entrybox_a1, entrybox_a2, entrybox_a3):
        artist = entry.get().strip()
        # ask for genre only when name is input and not in artist list
        if artist and artist not in artist_list:
            genre = askstring('Add artist', f"What is {artist}'s genre?")
            if genre:
                artist_list[artist] = genre
        entry.delete('0', 'end')  # clear entry
    print(artist_list)
```

Comment: Looked much simpler than I thought but it works exactly as I needed to. Thanks a lot. And thanks for the dictionary suggestion, I think it'll make everything simpler going forward, will definitely implement that.